# What's the difference between input:hover and input:active for a textfield?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

On focus, the text-field is already activated and has caret in it. Then is input:active relevant at all for a text-field?

Comment: Am really sorry. My concern is actually the difference between focus and active. https://jsfiddle.net/n5aLo2a1/

Comment: Sorry I misread, they have different semantics as @Oka points out (see his MDN links for more). Whilst it might not make sense to use one over the other in your case, that doesn't make the other redundant for all use cases.

Answer (score 3):

[`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) is when the user's cursor is on the element. [`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) is when the user's cursor is actively pressed on the the element.

On mobile this usually gets blended together.

For input elements there is also the [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) selector, when a user's focus is on the element, i.e., editing a text field.